# Python converting images in TIF format to PNG

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am running the code below to convert files from tifs to PNGs but the converted images isn't converting properly the new files are disrupted and with lines in half of the file as can be seen in the attached image. Any idea why would this happen please?[image].

```
import os
from PIL import Image

yourpath = os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[1].lower() == ".tif":
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".png"):
                print ("A png file already exists for %s" % name)
            # If a PNG is *NOT* present, create one from the tiff.
            else:
                outfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".png"
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, name))
                    print("Generating jpeg for %s" % name)
                    im.thumbnail(im.size)
                    im.save(outfile, "png", quality=100)
                except Exception as e:
                    print (e)
```

Running tiffinfo gives the following details:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 1024 Image Length: 1024
  Resolution: 5000, 5000 pixels/cm
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 1
  Planar Configuration: separate image planes
  ImageDescription: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Warning: this comment is an OME-XML metadata block, which contains crucial dimensional parameters and other important metadata. Please edit cautiously (if at all), and back up the original data before doing so. For more information, see the OME-TIFF web site: https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/latest/ome-model/ome-tiff/. --><OME xmlns="http://www.openmicroscopy.org/Schemas/OME/2016-06" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Creator="OME Bio-Formats 5.9.2" UUID="urn:uuid:5d7dfdcc-e0e9-4899-9aa2-64717b405232" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openmicroscopy.org/Schemas/OME/2016-06 http://www.openmicroscopy.org/Schemas/OME/2016-06/ome.xsd"><Image ID="Image:0" Name="p1_Bromophenol_1mM - Mark_and_Find 001/Position026 (RGB rendering)"><Pixels BigEndian="true" DimensionOrder="XYCZT" ID="Pixels:0" PhysicalSizeX="2.0" PhysicalSizeXUnit="┬Ám" PhysicalSizeY="2.0" PhysicalSizeYUnit="┬Ám" PhysicalSizeZ="1.0" PhysicalSizeZUnit="┬Ám" SizeC="3" SizeT="1" SizeX="1024" SizeY="1024" SizeZ="1" TimeIncrement="1.0" TimeIncrementUnit="s" Type="uint8"><Channel ID="Channel:0:0" Name="red" SamplesPerPixel="3"><LightPath/></Channel><TiffData FirstC="0" FirstT="0" FirstZ="0" IFD="0" PlaneCount="1"><UUID FileName="Position026 (RGB rendering) - 1024 x 1024 x 1 x 1 - 3 ch (8 bits).tif">urn:uuid:5d7dfdcc-e0e9-4899-9aa2-64717b405232</UUID></TiffData></Pixels></Image></OME>
  Software: OME Bio-Formats 5.9.2
```

Comment: There is very little to go wrong in your code. Do you get the same issues when saving as JPEG or PGM? If you do, you need to check your TIFFs. If other output formats are ok, try reinstalling PIL and `libpng`. By the way, omit `quality=100` on `im.save()` - it is already lossless.

Comment: I've just tried to convert a different tiff file, which converted fine without any issue. I have also tried to re-install PIL and libpng. I have found if i run my code on Anaconda i get an error message "tempfile.tif: Cannot read TIFF header".

Comment: You could try running `tiffinfo -D UnhappyImage.tif` to see if the file is ok. It's part of `libtiff` package. Or use **ImageMagick** to check an unhappy TIFF with `magick identify -verbose image.tif`.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with the tiffinfo of the image. Can you spot any issues?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with **OME Bio-Formats** to say. If you'd care to share an unhappy TIFF (Dropbox, Google Drive or somesuch) I'll have a try on my machine. You may like to add TIFF tag to your question to attract the right StackOverflow experts.

Comment: Here's a link with with one of the images https://www.dropbox.com/s/esbrd1ebmza5rg4/Position026%20%28RGB%20rendering%29%20-%201024%20x%201024%20x%201%20x%201%20-%203%20ch%20%288%20bits%29.tif?dl=0

Comment: Mmmm... not sure what is going on here! My PIL installation makes just as big a mess as yours and, surprisingly `tifffile` seems to get it wrong too. ImageMagick is happy with it, as is Python `wand`.

Comment: One thing I note... it goes wrong at exactly 1/3rd of the way across, like it has read one pixel plane but failed on the second and third. I note also that is planar config... mmm!